# Deleting items sharing similar features in a list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a nested list as the one below:

```
[[['a'],[24],214,1] ,[['b'],[24],312,1] ,[['a'],[24],3124,1] , [['c'],[24],34,1]]
```

and suppose I want to remove from the list all the items EXCEPT the one that has the maximum value for `item[2]` among items sharing the same letter in `item[0]`

So for example in the previous list I have two items sharing the same letter in `item[0]`:

```
[ ['a'],[24],214,1], [['a'],[24],3124,1] ]
```

and I want to remove the former since it has a lower value for `item[2]`.

The output list should then be:

```
[ [['b'],[24],312,1] ,[['a'],[24],3124,1] , [['c'],[24],34,1] ]
```

Can you suggest me a compact way to do it?

Comment: I am sorry. I will do that promptly.

Comment: Nicely corrected :) Does order matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is confusing, I have given the possibility of removing both the max and the min elements

```
>>> def foo(some_list, fn = max):
    #Create a dictionary, default dict won;t help much as 
    #we have to refer back to the value for an existing key
    #The dictionary would have item[0] as key
    foo_dict = dict()
    #Iterate through the list
    for e in some_list:
            #Check if the key exist
        if e[0][0] in foo_dict:
                    #and if it does, find the max of the existing value and the 
                    #new element. The key here is the second item
            foo_dict[e[0][0]] = fn(foo_dict[e[0][0]], e, key = lambda e:e[2])
        else:
                    #else consider the new element as the current max
            foo_dict[e[0][0]] = e
    return foo_dict.values()

>>> foo(somelist)
[[['a'], [24], 3124, 1], [['c'], [24], 34, 1], [['b'], [24], 312, 1]]
>>> foo(somelist,min)
[[['a'], [24], 214, 1], [['c'], [24], 34, 1], [['b'], [24], 312, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the returned order does not matter, you can try using `groupby` from `itertools` to group the items by their first element (after sorting by the first element), and then pulling out the maximum value with the `max` function (also, it should be noted that this returns a new list as opposed to modifying in place):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: l = [[['a'],[24],214,1] ,[['b'],[24],312,1] ,[['a'],[24],3124,1] , [['c'],[24],34,1]]

In [3]: result = []

In [4]: for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0]):
   ...:     result.append(max(g, key=lambda m: m[2]))
   ...:
   ...:

In [5]: result
Out[5]: [[['a'], [24], 3124, 1], [['b'], [24], 312, 1], [['c'], [24], 34, 1]]
```

Extending this a bit, if you want to maintain original order, you can modify `l` by including only those items the are in `results`, which will maintain order:

```
In [6]: l = [i for i in l if i in result]

In [7]: l
Out[7]: [[['b'], [24], 312, 1], [['a'], [24], 3124, 1], [['c'], [24], 34, 1]]
```

And to combine that into a true abomination of a one-liner, you could (but probably shouldn't :) ) do this:

```
In [10]: l = [[['a'],[24],214,1] ,[['b'],[24],312,1] ,[['a'],[24],3124,1] , [['c'],[24],34,1]]

In [11]: [i for i in l if i in [max(g, key=lambda m: m[2]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])]]
Out[11]: [[['b'], [24], 312, 1], [['a'], [24], 3124, 1], [['c'], [24], 34, 1]]
```

Comment: code golf : `[max(v, key=lambda item:item[2]) for _, v in groupby(sorted(l), lambda item: item[0])]`

Comment: @Boud Haha, I was honestly just about to type that with the disclaimer 'In an attempt to confuse anyone reading your code, you could try ...'. I will leave the glory to you!

Answer (score 0):

a few options that retain the original order and only remove any items where the comparator value is lower than the maximum.

```
def filter1(items):
    first = set(item[0][0] for item in items)
    compare = dict((f, max(item[2] for item in items if item[0][0] == f)) 
        for f in first)
    return  [item for item in items if item[2] >= compare[item[0][0]]]

def filter2(items):
    compare = {}
    for item in items:
        if ((item[0][0] in compare and item[2] > compare[item[0][0]])
            or (not item[0][0] in compare)):
            compare[item[0][0]] = item[2]
    return [item for item in items if item[2] >= compare[item[0][0]]]

def filter3(items):
    return [i for i in items if i[2] >= 
        max(j[2] for j in items if j[0][0]==i[0][0])]
```

filter3 is shortest but slowest if you have a large list. I guess filter2 would be the quickest.